# "Border" versus "perimeter" for Mandelbrot sets

Tags: fractals

Why do most writers used "border"--not "perimeter"--for Mandelbrot sets?

Comment: The $M$-Set doesn't have finite measurement of perimeter due to its fractal nature.  We usually use the term **exterior boundary**; in fact, the *"border"* has hausdorff dimension of $2$.

Comment: "Perimeter" usually refers to the *length* of the boundary of a shape.